# Does HashSet.equals() run in constant time?

Tags: java, collections, big-o, hashset, time-complexity

Just wondering if `HashSet.equals(anotherHashSet)` runs in constant time (also with a `ConcurrentHashSet` as argument), which I'm assuming it does for efficiency reasons. Can't see anything which mentions it, and a portion of the framework I'm building relies on the functionality (wouldn't want it to take too long!).

Edit: sorry, realised that there was no way that HashSet.equals() could ever run in constant time, since the elements can change while the hashcode for the elements in the map remains the same. Therefore, the best way to approach this problem would be to use hashcode. Does it reek of a code smell though?

Comment: Take a look at the code.

Comment: how can it be O(1) regardless of the number of elements in it?

Comment: @BrokenGlass If the "first" element is different?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: That's one special case and doesn't cover the general Big O - worst case you will have to compare all elements which is O(n)

Comment: @BrokenGlass Wouldn't the first element matching typically be the unusual special case? See also, worst case for QuickSort, say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at a typical [implementation](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ih5hvYJNSIA/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractSet.java&q=hashset&d=5&l=68) shows that it does `containsAll`.  Each check to contains is going to be O(1) and N of them are going to have to be made, so I reckon O(N).

Comment: Agreed (and updated).  The code alone is a bad way to explain it.  Jon Skeet's answer was better as the documentation is clearer.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I see from the code - it runs in linear time. The collection is iterated and each element is compared:

`equals(..`) in `AbstractSet` calls `containsAll(..)` in `AbstractCollection`, which gets the iterator and calls `contains(..)` for each element, and that in turn calls `map.containsKey(..)` which is `O(1)`. So `O(n)` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

Since the [`equals()` contract of a `Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) requires that the elements of the two `Set` objects must be identical, I don't think that it's possible to correctly implement this in O(1) in the general case (i.e. without having additional restrictions on the content types, for example).

One obvious exception is that if the incomming set has a different size, then the `equals()` operation can easily finish in O(1) (as long as `size()` itself is O(1)).

You could write a thin wrapper that caches the `hashCode()` each time it's calculated (and discards it when the `Set` changes). This would allow you to have a constant run time in most of the cases where the two `Set` objects are *not* identical. When you have to equal `Set` objects (or in cases of hash collisions) you will still have a O(n) runtime.

Comment: "I don't think that it's possible to correctly implement this in O(n)" - can you elaborate on what you mean by this? If `equals()` needs to visit each element (in both sets) once (or a constant number of times) this implies `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the sets.

Comment: @matt b: that was a typo (or probably a thinko), I meant to write O(1) instead (and fixed it now).

Answer (score 2):

How could it possibly run in constant time? The only sensible implementation (which is also the one used, which you can see if you check the API doc) is to iterate through one of the sets and for each element check whether the other one contains it, which is basically an O(n+m) operation.

Comment: Quite right. I forgot about how equals is normally implemented, and how the implementation can do custom checks for equality.